# curl implementation using c for SOAP

Tags: c, xml, curl, soap, upnp

I am building a C program that uses libcurl to send a XML file by 
HTTP POST. This is a part of SOAP implementation in UPnP
I am sending SOAP request  and the response should be saved in an xml file

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#define URL "http://192.168.1.159:8200/ctl/ContentDir"

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fwrite(ptr,size,nmeb,stream);
}

size_t read_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
    return fread(ptr,size,nmeb,stream);
}

int main(char * Browse_request, char * response)
{

        FILE * rfp = fopen("Browse_request.xml", "r");
        if(!rfp) {
            perror("Read File Open:");
        }

        FILE * wfp = fopen("response.xml", "w+"); //File pointer to write the soap response
        if(!wfp) {
            perror("Write File Open:");
        }

        struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
        header = curl_slist_append (header, "Content-Type:text/xml; Charset=UTF-8");
        header = curl_slist_append (header, "SOAPAction: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1#Browse");
        header = curl_slist_append (header, "Content-Length:0");

        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data);  //Reads xml file to be sent via POST operation
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, rfp); 
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);  //Gets data to be written to file
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, wfp);  //Writes result to file
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)-1);

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L);            
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

            return 0;
        }

}
```

It gives an error, 400 bad request.

If I do the same using command line, i am getting expected result and the result is saved in response.xml. the command that i use is:

```
curl -v -o response.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml; Charset="UTF-8"" -H "SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1#Browse"" -d @Browse_request.xml -X POST http://192.168.1.159:8200/ctl/ContentDir
```

my browse_request.xml which is same for command line and program is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:Browse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:Service:ContentDirectory:1">
            <ObjectID>0</ObjectID>
            <BrowseFlag>BrowseDirectChildren</BrowseFlag>
            <Filter>*</Filter>
            <StartingIndex>1</StartingIndex>
            <RequestedCount>5</RequestedCount>
            <SortCriteria></SortCriteria>
        </u:Browse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

when i try to implement using c program, why is it giving 400 bad request

thanks in advance

Comment: As I said in the other question, compare the messages you send (from command line and from your app) with e.g. Wireshark. Content-Length header as an example is wrong in your app.

Comment: when i compare it with wireshark, using command line, xml file comes after headers. but through program, it displays, Expect:100-continue and then terminated though i dont have expect header in my program.

Comment: I am not able to eliminate the expect: 100 continue error with how many ever commands. help me in eliminating this

Comment: And content-length? You seem to be setting it to 0 which is wrong.

Comment: Though i set it to 479 which is the content-length that i get through command line result, I am getting the same error

Comment: and is this the only difference in the messages that you didn't mention? There is almost certainly a difference between the two requests, and it's very likely to be the reason. Also, is the return code 400 or 100 -- you have mentioned both?